# How to use Liferay Mobile SDK 6.2.18 to generate jar libraries now that http is deprecated by both Gradle and Maven?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, liferay-6, liferay-6.2

In my current project we're working on mantaining/developing mobile (android/iOS) apps that use the services of the client's website  (liferay 6.2). Whenever the guys in Backend generate new services (or just update an existing service to a new version with new features) we need to use the Liferay Mobile SDK 6.2.18, which uses really dated gradle 1 and http protocol, to generate a new jar library to allow the app call those new services.

As I guess many will know already, gradle recently deprecated HTTP in favour of HTTPS, and maven shortly after followed suit, so now we are completely unable to generate the jar libraries.

Unfortunately, our client won't accept upgrading Liferay to 7 - which Backend guys tell me would solve this bump in the road - so we need to find a workaround to this situation. I've tried searching both google in general (filtering by last month results) and SO in particular, but no dice.

Has anyone else here who found themselves in this situation managed to work around it?

Comment: We are having the same issue in our project. Any help would be appreciated. If you find the solution please post it here.