# How can I get in Android the auth token from the liferay 6 login screenlet in order to use it with REST API calls?

Tags: android, session, kotlin, liferay-6

We use Liferay Mobile in my Android project in order for the app to call the Liferay 6.2 backend services. Since the issue mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60089747/how-to-use-liferay-mobile-sdk-6-2-18-to-generate-jar-libraries-now-that-http-is), though, I've been tasked with researching if it would be possible to use the REST API calls instead. Public methods are OK, they work as intended. Private ones - those that in the app demand the user to be logged in - are tougher. I've gone through the generated library trying to find the classes that do carry the session token - all I need for the private API calls to work - and found the `Session` class from the `com.liferay.mobile.android.service` package, yet no way to access to the current session itself.

If it is possible to have access to the Session generated within the Login screenlet, how can I get to it?